# how can typehead allows only list values else give alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typehead

I am using typeahead.js 0.9.3, Is it possible that typehead allows only the items in the list not manual text enter by user. It does not allow user to do so OR after any event it check wether the value is present in list or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote:'sale/files/search_part.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
  });
});
```

I am not good at javascript & JQuery, so don't know how to set array value to list so can below code check whether it exist in list or not. Please help

```
var myData = [...]; // how to assign output list to this array?

$("#partno").typeahead({source : myData}).blur(validateSelection);

function validateSelection() {
  if(source.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) {
    alert('Error : element not in list!');
  }
}
```

Input field

```
<input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"  id="partno" >
```

Comment: Which typeahead plugin are you using? There are several available

Comment: typeahead.js 0.9.3

Comment: You could use the `notFound` / `empty` custom template to show your message. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options

Comment: Thank you for your time, but non of them will work in my case as "notfound" is for query requested and "empty" is use for query purpose.

Answer (score 0):

assign output list to myData

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myData = [];
$.ajax({
    url : url_example.php,
    data:{
        condition : 'text'
    },
    dataType:'json',
    method:'POST',
    success:function(result){
        myData = result.data
    },error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error!');
    }
})
```

});

you can readmore here
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/